# Magento 2: How to show loader while customer-data is loading from server?

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend, ajax, customer-data

```js
  define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
   'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        isLoggedIn: function () {
           this.customer = customerData.get('customer');
           if (!this.customer().firstname) {
              return false;
           }
           return true;
       }
    });

}
```

When the customer login and the customer data is being loaded by ajax from server, `isLoggedIn` returns `false`.

But this is not correct as the customer has logged in and local-storage update is in progress.

How to get the logged in state while data is loading from server in 'customer-data.js'?